# How to identify which version of Yarn is used by a project?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

For the [OSS Review Toolkit project](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort), I would like to identify which version of yarn is used by a given project in a given repository.

Which criteria should be used ?
There is:

- `package.json/packageManager` which requires Corepack and may not be used by all projects.
- look at the version `.yarn/releases/*`
- check the `.yarnrc` file: if this is `yarnrc.yml` then this is Yarn 2+.
- the version in `yarn.lock` seems to not be related to the Yarn version used for the project (but please correct me if I am wrong).

Is there any other criteria that could be used to disambiguiate if this is a Yarn 1, 2 or 3 project ?

Comment: Why not run `yarn --version`?

Comment: I understand what you mean: even if you have Yarn1 installed globally, having a project configured with Yarn2+ with a `.yarnrc` and a `.yarn/releases/XXX.cjs` file, calling `yarn` returns the correct version, because the file in `.yarn/releases/XXX.cjs` will be called.

Comment: This raise a new concern :)

If I have a project and put some malicious code in the `.yarn/release/XXX.cjs` file, won't I be able to compromise the users running `yarn` in my project source tree ?

Comment: Yes, but at this point it's much easier to just put a malicious postinstall script, either inside the project or hidden within of its dependencies ‍♀️

Answer (score 3):

The frustrating answer is that there *isn't* an easy way (although there probably *should* be). Running `yarn -v` will simply show your global yarn version; not the local repo. You need to look for the same hints you listed.

Perhaps your collaborators can agree to make an arbitrary `.yarnver` file that simply contains something like:

```js
1.22.11
```